# NULL macro and nul

Tags: c

If a constant is used mostly in the code, we will use macro to define a constant. 
Why is the "NULL" defined as a macro and why nul("\0") is not defined as macro ?

Comment: Why is 1 not defined as a macro `ONE`? What's the point of having a macro for `'\0'`, aka `0`? For `NULL` it indicates that it's a pointer.

Comment: @DanielFischer: except that `NULL` isn't guaranteed to be a pointer. So it actually only indicates that the author would quite like you to imagine that it's a pointer but doesn't care whether it really is or not ;-)

Comment: Right, @Steve, I should have written "used in pointer context" or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's probably some subtle reason that could be used to justify the difference, but I expect there's just no demand for a macro for the zero character (named `NUL` in ASCII).

`NULL` can be any null pointer constant of the implementation's choosing, it might be an integer or a pointer. So it's used when you need a null pointer constant, but you don't want to give readers the impression that it matters exactly *which* null pointer constant is used. Basically, you can use it to initialize/assign a pointer, when you want it to be a null pointer. You can also use it when testing whether a pointer is null.

Not everyone bothers using `NULL`. `0` is a permitted value of `NULL`, so anywhere that you can *portably* use `NULL`, you can use `0` instead. Personally I don't think the C language would be any poorer if it didn't have `NULL`. In particular, you can get into trouble passing `NULL` in a varargs function, because people generally think it's a pointer, and it converts to a pointer if required, but varargs functions don't convert it. So if it's not a pointer where a pointer is needed then you get UB. The same applies to functions without a prototype in scope.

The macro you propose would always expand to an `int` with value 0. "We need more ways of writing zero" doesn't seem to me the kind of thing that would excite the C standard committee to take action, even if it was proposed. If there was a set of macros naming the characters in the basic execution set, then having one for `NUL` in that set would make sense. But people seem happy to write `'a'` instead of `LATIN_LOWERCASE_A`, `'\n'` instead of `LINEFEED`, and `0` or `'\0'` instead of `NUL`.

Answer (score 2):

A macro has to expand to something that is not a macro. It's not [turtles all the way down](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down).

Comment: Correct.the ascii value of the escape sequence is 27. so whenever we need to check whether the pointer containing a string has completed or not we can use the macro defined with the value 27 instead of using '\0'.

Comment: @Angus The ASCII value of `'\0'` is 0, it has nothing to do with `'\ESC'`?

Comment: @Angus: ASCII 27 is `ESC`, but that has nothing to do with the zero terminating character.

Comment: So NULL is (void *)0 = address pointing to 0 loc and nul is 0. I understood now :)

Comment: @Angus `NULL` may be `(void*)0`, or plain `0`, or something else, it's up to the implementation. But it must be a null pointer constant.

Comment: Although NULL may not be address zero, it'll always be treated as 0 (the correct form is handled internally). e.g. `p = NULL; if (p) ...` will fail.

Answer (score 1):

`\0` is an octal character constant (representing binary 0), and so can be placed in a `char`. NULL is not.

`NULL` means an address that cannot be accessed, and its internal value is implementation dependent. It always represents 0 when used as a pointer in your code though, so a test like `if (p == NULL)` is identical to `if (!p)`.